# Use of Lodash get in Gatsby/Contentful

Tags: reactjs, graphql, lodash, gatsby, contentful

Example of the Gatsby/Contentful Starter Code:

```
import get from 'lodash/get'
    ...
    const post = get(this.props, 'data.contentfulBlogPost')
    const siteTitle = get(this.props, 'data.site.siteMetadata.title')
```

Why are they using lodash 'get' instead of directly refering to the graphql-query result 'data' in the html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using 'get' from lodash, which can handle some cases that `this.props.data` is `undefined`, to avoid the code throwing some error if you try to access `this.props.data.contentfulBlogPost`.

You can also using `this.props?.data?.contentfulBlogPost`